# force_ssl redirect from http://example.com to https://secure.example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, https, ssl-certificate

I have SSL working in production on Heroku. Except I set it up so that SSL is used only with the https://secure.example.com.

In my Rails application and DNS manager (Go Daddy), how can I ensure that all visits (`www.domain.com/`, `domain.com/`, `https://domain.com`) all forward to `https://secure.domain.com`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your application controller, make a before filter with:

```
def redirect_secure
  redirect_to subdomain: "secure", protocol: "https" if request.protocol == "http"
end
```